# sudo-like behavior with python

Tags: python

I have a Python script, let's call it myscript.py, which, upon launch, asks for a password, then does a bunch of things (think, server access / ssh / sftp / etc.) using the password. The script is stateless, that is, if the script is launched again, concurrently to the first launch, or, immediately after the first launch completes, it will ask for the password.

What I intend to achieve is: if myscript.py is launched again, within a short interval from the first launch, it shouldn't ask for the password, that is, I want it to have a "state" and remember the password for a short period of time (hence, "sudo-like behavior").

How would I go about doing this?

I am open to (a) purely python based solution, or (b) external password manager which can be called from within the script, or (c) splitting up into a "daemon" and interacting with it somehow, ....

Comment: there are multiple opinionated solutions for this. Off the top of my hat, you can read the password from an environment variable - this way, you can decide whether to set it for this particular session (`MYSCRIPT_PWD=... ./myscript.py`) only or keep for subsequent invocations (`export MYSCRIPT_PWD=...; ./myscript.py`)

Comment: [Python-LDAP](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.2/)?

Comment: Note that sudo doesn’t remember your password, just [that you are authenticated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37299/how-does-sudo-remember-you-already-entered-roots-password). How many connections are you making? Leaving them open could be a pretty neat solution that doesn’t involve storing a password. Also, if everything is SSH-based (sounds like it could be with “server access / ssh / sftp”), you can use ssh-agent to store an unlocked SSH key instead of a password. Public-key authentication is much safer than password authentication.